ValueError: Unknown layer: 'CustomScaleLayer'
I am building a model using InceptionResNEtV2 for my image dataset training.
My model looks like:
`inception_resnet = InceptionResNetV2(weights = "imagenet",
                                 include_top = False,
                                 input_tensor = Input(shape = (224, 224, 3)))
inception_resnet.trainable = False

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
headmodel = inception_resnet.output
headmodel = Flatten()(headmodel)
headmodel = Dense(500, activation = "relu")(headmodel)
headmodel = Dense(250, activation = "relu")(headmodel)
headmodel = Dense(4, activation = "sigmoid")(headmodel)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

model = Model(inputs = inception_resnet.input, outputs = headmodel)
model.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 1e-4))
model.summary()

I have trained my dataset on the following model and saved it as
model.save('detection.h5')
When I am trying to load my saved model for prediction using
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('detection.h5')
It is giving me an error as:
ValueError: Unknown layer: 'CustomScaleLayer'.
Can someone help me with model loading for prediction...
I have tried using
model = tf.keras.models.load_model((path),custom_objects={'KerasLayer':hub.KerasLayer})
But it didn't solve my problem.

Depending on your TF version, the .h5 format is a legacy format. Did you try saving and loading with .keras or .tf ending? Maybe that's the problem. The CustomScaleLayer is a custom layer from InceptionResNEtV2, it could be that newer formats can handle custom layers better.
